# error in url rewriting using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

hi i want to rewrite `http://immortalgoddess.com/index.php?/welcome/index`  url to 
`http://immortalgoddess.com/index.php?mainpage.html`.I use codignator framework in my project.
I tried this code but it did'nt works

```
 RewriteEngine  on

    RewriteRule ^http://immortalgoddess.com/index.php?mainpage.html$ http://immortalgoddess.com/index.php?/welcome/index
```

if anyone knows please reply

Comment: I believe this question would be a better fit for StackOverflow's sister site ServerFault. (It doesn't really pertain to programming).

Comment: mod_rewrite questions are on topic on SO as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /welcome/index
RewriteRule /index.php$ /index.php?mainpage.html [L]
```

If it doesn't work try to remove the slash:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} /welcome/index
RewriteRule index.php$ /index.php?mainpage.html [L]
```

Tell me if it works!

### And now two hints:

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)